# When does the iOS developer license auto-renewal happen when active?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When specifically does the auto-renewal for the developer license happen? If I have activated it, say, a month ago, and in a couple of days it will expire, when will it auto-renew? Will it happen exactly when it expires?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, auto-renewal takes place the second the membership would otherwize expire. No worries.

Alternatively you can manually renew it 30 days upfront though, but this does not give you any advantages.

Comment: So does that mean I get new agreements on that day as well? Including the Paid Application contracts?

Comment: Contracts change from time to time, so you have to agree them. This process is independent of your membership renewal.

Comment: So the "effective date" is also the expiration date? What is the difference between effective date and expiration?

Comment: I do not get the question.

Comment: There's a contract type called paid applications. It says for me that the "effective date" has passed, let's say it was november 1st when the effective date passed, and there's an expiration date, in which we'll say is on november 20th. What is the difference between them? And also assume the membership for developer license is on november 20th as well.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?